# Is it possible to collect data from one page and autofill it onto a form on a different site using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

A site I am working on requires user information to be collected from a form when the user presses the submit button. The site will then take the information and plug it into a more robust form on a different page, so the user does not have to retype the information twice.

Is this possible using javascript?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like something that should be handled on the back end.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought... If anyone knows of any way to do this front-end, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user leaves the current page, the JavaScript on the original page is no longer running, They will load up the other page and run that page's JavaScript.

Do you have ownership of both pages?

If so, then you can leverage the form *GET* to pass information across pages, so the next page will have a [Query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and JavaScript can parse that.

Another way to move data from one page to another is to use [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html). So it really depends on how much data you want to move around.

But I highly recommend that you leverage the server-side technology to handle the form *GET* or *POST* and carry information across pages.

Comment: That is the answer I was afraid of. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

This completely depends on the OTHER site. You can have a form with the same field names and post it to the same URL the other site's form uses.

BUT - if that site checks to see where the original post came from, it may block you out.